# How browsers keep sync with the W3C standards?

Tags: browser, standards, w3c

I always follow https://www.w3.org/ to track the updates on CSS or HTML. Today morning when I was checking, W3C published the new draft on CSS-GRID.

So I want to know how browsers keep track of these new changes W3C made and how frequent they update their browsers and release it to affect the new changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't keep up. They write the specs for the W3C, sometimes creating an implementation first and using what they learn during that process to help them write the spec, sometimes writing a spec before implementation. But mostly it's an iterative process with partial implementation informing spec changes and spec changes informing the next round of implementations. Sometimes specs never get implemented, and occasionally implementations get withdrawn. Those specs then quietly die.

Grid layouts, in particular, were first implemented by IE, and then submitted by Microsoft for standardisation. The latest version of that standard differs substantially from that first implemented in IE.

Comment: If thats the case then there is no reliable way to check, which version of W3c draft we are using, or let me put it another way,,,Is there any way to check the mapping between browser version and W3C draft version???

Comment: No, there isn't. Caniuse.com will often provide information on how current and recent browser versions match up to the latest (or a recent) version of the spec, but there's no simple mapping. Any given implementation may include functionality from one or more new paragraphs of a given draft, but not other new functionality from the same draft.